# Reading whole line with std::cin

Tags: c++

I would like to figure out how to read a whole line (including spaces) with `std::cin`. I am aware of the existence of `std::getline`, I would just like to figure out how to do it with `std::cin` so I can better understand iostream in C++. I've tried using a for loop with `std::cin`, however it keeps reading past the end of the line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do use `std::cin` when you call `std::getline`... Perhaps you meant with `operator>>`? In that case, it skips leading whitespace by default.

Comment: @chris Yes, sorry i meant with the operator, for example `std::cin >> i;`

Comment: Using a screwdriver to pound in nails isn't really the most effective way to better understand screwdrivers.

Comment: You should take a look at how getline works. Hint take a look at [std::istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/). The first signature for the function extracts a single character from the underlying stream

Comment: `std::getline()` is the correct function to use. In case you were wondering, the *member functions* `istream::getline()` and `istream::get()` are for raw character buffers, not for `std::string`s for which `std::getline()` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Also the cin << only allows us to enter one word into a string.
However, there is a cin function that reads text containing blanks.

```
std::cin.get(name, MAX);
```

get will read all characters including spaces until Max characters have been read or the end of line character (‘\n’) is reached and will put them into the name variable.
You should decide what is MAX.

Comment: You'd want `std::cin.getline()`... `get()` will leave the line ending in the string.